# How can I pass a long type value into the parameter of a function with integer as the return type?

Tags: c, function, types

I'm having trouble setting up the code for a function. The error message show: conflicting types.

So I think it's because my return type is different from the value in the parameter. So I was wondering if it's possible to have different types of values in the parameter and how to fix this code.

```
//prompt user to enter the credit card number and print it on screen
long get_credit()
{
   long credit_number = get_long("Number: ");
   //printf("Number: %li\n",credit_number); //debugging
  return credit_number;
}

//digits lengther
int get_digit(long credit_number)
{
       long credit = credit_number; //length of the number of digits given by the user
       int length = 0;
       while(credit != 0)
       {
       credit = credit/10 ;
       length ++ ;
       }
       return length;
}
```

This is the error message it's showing me.

```
credit_v2.c:154:5: error: conflicting types for 'get_digit'
int get_digit(long credit_number)
    ^
credit_v2.c:7:5: note: previous declaration is here
int get_digit(void); //calculate the number of digits
    ^
```

Again, thank you guys for all the help!

Comment: change the line `int get_digit(void);` to `int get_digit(long credit_number);`. It is line 7 of credit_v2.c

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're getting this error because the prototype of the function doesn't match the definition.

As the error message states, you declared the function as `int get_digit(void);`, i.e. a function which takes no arguments and returns an `int`.  However, the definition of the function shows that it takes a single argument of type `long`.

You need to make the prototype match the definition.

```
int get_digit(long credit_number); //calculate the number of digits
```

Answer (score 2):

Change line 7, from:

```
int get_digit(void);
```

to:

```
int get_digit(long credit_number);
```